# .htaccess RewriteRule is not redirecting the page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

im trying to redirect a link like this:

http://spicyyeti.com/strangers/2

to its equivalent:

http://spicyyeti.com/strangers/strangers.php?img=2

and so in .htaccess ive written:

```
RewriteRule ^/strangers/([0-9]+)$ /strangers/strangers.php?img=$1 [R=301]
```

but nothing is happening. i can't see what's wrong--am i writing them in the wrong order? here is my full .htaccess just in case there's something conflicting that i'm not seeing:

```
# use php in html files i think
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html

DirectoryIndex home.html 

RewriteEngine On

#removes html extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC]

RewriteRule ^/strangers/([0-9]+)$ /strangers/strangers.php?img=$1 [R=301]
```

by the way, which link will actually display in the browser?

Comment: Your first rule is going to match and rewrite to `strangers/2.html`, which I assume doesn't exist on your server so you will get a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first rule is going to match and rewrite to `strangers/2.html`, you'll need a condition to exclude the `strangers` URI from the first rule:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/strangers/.*$
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^strangers/([0-9]+)$ /strangers/strangers.php?img=$1 [L]
```

I removed the 301 flag from the last rule. I'm assuming you don't really want to redirect to `/strangers/strangers.php?img=2`, but rather show `strangers/2` in the browser url bar while apache executes `/strangers/strangers.php?img=$1` under the covers.

Comment: thanks, that worked. how come we exclude the strangers directory from the .html extension removal, but in the rewrite we refer to the pattern without its extension?

Comment: The `RewriteCond` is just a string match against what the browser requested, it's not referring to a real directory. It will match any URI that starts with `/strangers/`, the `.*` is a wildcard for basically anything. You could also put a pattern there if you wanted to. The same is true for the first argument of the rewriterule, it is a string match against the browser requested. You could put `strangers/(.*)$ there as well, it would take anything as opposed to ([0-9]+) which is only matching and capturing numbers from 0 to 9.